# Apache camel interceptors

Tags: java, apache-camel

please help me to solve the problem. I'm going to intercept message before "endpoint1" but get an **Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[Message: [Body is instance of org.apache.camel.StreamCache]]**

```
<interceptSendToEndpoint uri="endpoint_1">
  <transform>
    <method bean="logMessage" method="log"/>
  </transform>
</interceptSendToEndpoint>

<route id="xxx">
<from uri="yyy"/>
.
.
.
<to uri="endpoint_1" pattern="InOut"/>
</route>
```

Comment: you should check what is it that you are getting in endpoint_1. As the exception says it is of type StreamCache. Try to put your `interceptSendToEndpoint` block inside `route` block

Comment: I've tried, but get the same error.

Comment: What version of Camel do you use. And where do you get that exception, and can you edit the question to include the full stacktrace, and also show the code for that log bean you call.

Comment: I've found the reason: I have to unmarshal it before calling bean's method.